# React Native Android Keyboard custom height

Tags: android, keyboard, react-native

Android Keyboard shows with suggestion area and it hides the icons below `textbox`.
How can I move the window a little bit more in Android?
In `iOS` I can customise the height to be moved up.
Can I do this in Android?
And if this is not possible, how can I disable keyboard suggestion area?
I have attached two screenshots.

Without Keyboard

[image: Without Keyboard]

With Keyboard showing

[image: Keybaord hides the icons below textbox]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this in android, pretty much all the keyboards will act the same, but you can give RedrawKeyboard a try, it's a keyboard customization app, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the KeyboardAvoidingView component can help you avoid the whole keyboard.

try something like this:

```
import { Platform, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';

<KeyboardAvoidingView
  behavior={Platform.select({ ios: 'padding' })}
/>
  ....rest of the code
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```